# What happens to apps, files, objects in a VM if it gets deleted

Tags: virtualization, deletion

Usually, when a file is deleted on your computer, it is simply unlinked.  The file data is still stored on your disk, there's just nothing pointing to that spot in the memory, and the OS interprets that block of mem as free and open to be overwritten.  Using VM, you are able to partition a portion of your HD dedicated to the VM, and keep it isolated from the root system, and a lot of people use VMs to test malicious code / programs, etc.  Assuming the VM gets deleted, is this process the same?  Does this mean that the malicious code is now unlinked in your HD fully intact, but no longer partitioned into an isolated system?  Do VM workstations perform due diligence upon deletion and scramble the partitioned HD?

Answer (score 4):

#### Virtual Block Devices

Usually, you don't partition your HDD to give it to a VM. Usually, a "virtual disk", which is just a file on your HDD, is used. This is sometimes called a "Virtual Block Device", and has many advantages. For example, disks can be re-sized my simply making the file larger, or backed up by copying a file. And since the files are "sparse files", you can create larger virtual disks for multiple machines without needing as much storage space.

So what happens when you delete the VM? Well, either the file remains on your disk, so you can create a new VM and have that use the same disk, or you can delete the file. The consequences are identical to that of deleting a normal file.

#### Dedicated Partitions for VMs

As you asked in your question, it's possible to use a physical partition for a virtual machine.

If you delete your VM, then the partition remains. In all likelihood, it's probably a bootable partition as well, so you could in theory boot into it. This process was sometimes used on MacOS, with Windows installed as secondary OS. You could either boot into Windows, or you could boot into MacOS and boot Windows as a VM.

In order to delete the disk, you have to either re-format it or overwrite it. Re-formatting is much faster, but leaves the VM data there, so parts of it could likely be recovered again. Overwriting it is more safe, but also takes much longer, depending on the size of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming the VM gets deleted, is this process the same?

No, a VM and its contents are different entities. The "VM" is just a configuration file defining, among other resources, the storage it will use. Deleting a VM does not mean deleting the storage. Your hipervisor may ask you to delete the VM and its contents, but that is not always the case.

> Does this mean that the malicious code is now unlinked in your HD fully intact, but no longer partitioned into an isolated system?

No, the malicious code is still stored in the virtual device (usually a very large file that stores the data). It's like having an ext4 device on a MSDOS. The data is there, but the OS don't have access to it.

> Do VM workstations perform due diligence upon deletion and scramble the partitioned HD?

Usually they don't. Usually they ask if you want to keep the virtual disks, and don't do a secure delete on the files. I never saw a hipervisor asking to delete data from a partition.